# How to prevent VBA Delete Cell Range Run time error

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a very simple VBA function to delete the last set of data to be inputted into a form. For some reason this has started to bug and produce a

> Runtime error of 1004

Can I check is this the best way to complete the task required or is there a better way as it has error-ed.

My code is as follows:

```
Sub Clealast_Click()

Worksheets("Holidays Form").Rows("b24:e24").Delete

End Sub
```

This works from a button on the page and is set to clear to selected range.

Comment: rows ("B24:E24") would be the same row regardless.. Try `range("B24").entirerow.delete`

Comment: Your sub should never have worked in the first place, and even if it had worked it wouldn't have deleted the selected range but a specific range, namely `B24:E24`. Do you want to delete the entire (selected) row, or only the contents of the selected cells, or specific cells in a selected row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You example is trying to delete a `Range`, not a `Row`

To delete the entire row, do not specify a column with it:

```
Worksheets("Holidays Form").Rows("24:24").Delete
```

And since you are specifying only one row, you can simplify it:

```
Worksheets("Holidays Form").Rows("24").Delete
```

Or

```
Worksheets("Holidays Form").Rows(24).Delete
```